# Php Mysql search query with multiple words

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to search database with maximum 3 words match with multiple fields and i am using given given code:

```
$hotel_name=trim($_GET['hotel_src_key']);
$search_type=trim($_GET['hotel_src']);
$pieces = explode(" ", $hotel_name);

//echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

$search1=$pieces[0];
$search2=$pieces[1]; 
$search3=$pieces[2];
echo $search1.$search2.$search3; 

if($search_type=="any hotel")
{
$rest ="WHERE hotel_name like '%$search1%' AND hotel_name like '%$search2%'AND hotel_name like '%$search3%' OR city like '%$search1%' AND city like '%$search2%' AND city like '%$search3%'";
}

if($search_type=="hotel city"){
$rest="WHERE city like '%$search1%' AND city like '%$search2%' AND city like '%$search3%'";
}

if($search_type=="hotel name"){
$rest="WHERE hotel_name like '%$search1%' AND hotel_name like '%$search2%' AND hotel_name like '%$search3%'";
}


$stmt=$connc->query("SELECT * FROM  hotels  $rest ORDER BY h_id ASC");
$rc = $stmt->num_rows;
```

But its not working as i want bcoz when i search hotel with keyword `"agra jaipur delhi"` in `(search_type=any hotel)`, then results shows `0`
how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: try to add the bracket for this "WHERE (hotel_name like '%$search1%' AND hotel_name like '%$search2%'AND hotel_name like '%$search3%' ) OR (city like '%$search1%' AND city like '%$search2%' AND city like '%$search3%')

Comment: when i type keyword `agra jaipur` agra jaipur is city then results is 0 when i type keyword only `agra` one word then working good

Comment: @ranbir no response from you. deleting my answer. i think its not useful for you

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE hotel_name like :search1 OR hotel_name like :search2 or hotel_name like :search3
```

and use prepared statement http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php if you are using PDO or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php if you are using mysqli

Comment: i am using `mysqli`